# Does GitHub Linguist support prefix wildcards for linguist-vendored?

Tags: github, github-linguist

In GitHub's documentation on `linguist`, the [section](https://github.com/github/linguist#using-gitattributes) on using the `.gitattributes` file says a path can be marked as vendored, and thus ignored in the repository's statistics tracking, with:

```
special-vendored-path/* linguist-vendored
```

However, is it possible to have linguist mark directories as vendored that may be nested in directories containing non-vendored code?

I tried adding a line styled as `*/special-vendored-path/* linguist-vendored` to my `.gitattributes`, but that didn't cause the GitHub code-proportion information to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match a directory inside an arbitrary arborescence of directories, you need **double asterisks**:

```
**/special-vendored-path/* linguist-vendored
```

Note, however, that double asterisks are not needed at the end of paths. For example, `test1/*` will match `test1/test2/test3/file`.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks, this allowed me to filter the vendored code as desired.